# What does the "Expiration Date" indicate under the "User License" section (located in Company Information)?

Tags: licenses, userlicense

Not able to locate any documentation from Salesforce on what this means exactly. It does not correspond to Start/End Dates indicated in our contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your organization has that many valid licenses till the mentioned date. If not renewed will expire at 00:00 hour on the mentioned date. It should match the subscription date that is an end of the contract if not matching contact support or your salesforce appointed account manager.